# Rust - Lifetime of struct member depends on another struct member

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to write a Rust struct. The struct owns a Reference counted pointer to a string and also owns a vector of string slices to the same string.

Furthermore I'm trying to write a function to generate this struct. I'm unsure how to proceed.

```rust
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    rc_string: Rc<String>,
    vec: Vec<&'a str>
}

fn build_my_struct<'a>(s: &Rc<String>) -> MyStruct<'a> {
    let rc_string = s.clone();
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(&rc_string[0..2]);

    MyStruct {
        rc_string: rc_string,
        vec: vec
    }
}
```

```sh
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `rc_string`
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
11 |       vec.push(&rc_string[0..2]);
   |                 --------- `rc_string` is borrowed here
12 | 
13 | /     MyStruct {
14 | |         rc_string: rc_string,
15 | |         vec: vec
16 | |     }
   | |_____^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I understand that the `vec` variable has borrowed the `rc_string`. The compiler doesn't like returning `vec` because it has the borrow to the local variable `rc_string`.

However `rc_string` is being returned as well? The string slices are valid for the duration of the life of `MyStruct.rc_string`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to borrow `Rc` for life time `'a` as well. Compiler needs to know that slice from a `String` is living in `'a` or not. In this case we need to borrow `Rc` for `'a` and compiler will know inner of `Rc` will also live in `'a`.

If you clone `s` and assign it to `rc_string`:

- `s` will stay in the function's scope as borrowed `Rc` for lifetime `'a`
- `rc_string` will be the owner of the `Rc` **pointer**

and compiler won't be able to know slice of a `rc_string` is living for `'a` or not.

Using slice from a `s` will work :

```rust
fn build_my_struct<'a>(s: &'a Rc<String>) -> MyStruct<'a> {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    let rc_string = s.clone();

    vec.push(&s[0..2]);

    MyStruct { rc_string, vec }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=95183132643de3f41536b06d2c31dd53)

Comment: @JamesWelchman The code in your second question will work with the same way, please check [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e2d60a493392091514ee0016a198f56c). You can't return  slice from a moved content unless it lives in static lifetime.

Comment: In my original code I use the `Rc` pointer *because* the lifetime of `MyStruct` extends beyond the lifetime of the`Rc<String>` in the calling function.

Just to be clear - I can't move *both* a String and a slice of the string into a return value?

Comment: Basically [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=959c1f59a29376cca0311094f5e6cdd2) is always impossible.

Comment: @JamesWelchman borrow checker's duty is preventing you from facing with dangling pointers, you can create a struct both String and it's slice but there is a possibility at runtime you can move(or  even drop) String value from a field of struct without moving or dropping slices from that string. With this you can have dangling pointers

Comment: @JamesWelchman [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=959c1f59a29376cca0311094f5e6cdd2) is not possible because according to our definition `&s` needs to live in `my_struct`'s lifetime argument. It is a bit confusing because you are not dropping the real string but borrow checker is not able to know the string is trapped inside a `Rc` pointer.